# Active SideBar Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My jquery code does not perform **active sidebar** action. where did I mistake, can anyone tell us?
Where should I have to change..? should I have make somechange in html code..?
This is my jquery code

```js
$(function() {
  $(".sidebar-menu li").removeClass("active");
  $("#liaccounts").addClass("active");
  $("#selectAll").click(function() {
    // $(".checkAll").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    var checked = ($(".checkAll").prop('checked') == false) ? true : false;
    $(".checkAll").prop('checked', checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar-menu">
  <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
  <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
  <nav class="mt-2">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
      <!--
        Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
        with font-awesome or any other icon font library
      -->
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{url('dashboard')}}" class="nav-link active">
          <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
          <p>Dashboard</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{url('contact')}}" class="nav-link">
          <i class="nav-icon fas fa-file"></i>
          <p>Contact</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{url('accounts')}}" class="nav-link">
          <i class="nav-icon fas fa-user"></i>
          <p>Accounts</p>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *Active sidebar action*

Comment: @Nicolas means when I click the Accounts section in sidebar, then it shows accounts section active (means anything color will be change, that indicates the account section is clicked).

Comment: There seams to have a lot of information missing : there is no element `#liaccounts`.  `#selectAll` does not exists either. There is no logic to add `active` class to any `<li>`. Could you please revise your question because we cannot help you at this point.

Comment: @Nicolas actually this code is not written by me, So I want to debug this code, It is not working...so where I have to put the ID and Class in html code, can you tell me..? I think there is #liaccounts id is missing in html code..